# How to perform code signing on a python script?

Tags: python, code-signing

How to perform code signing on a python script? Like in Powershell, there is **Set-AuthenticodeSignature** for signing scripts.
I have already tried using Microsoft **signtool.exe** but it only works for EXEs and DLLs, not for PY/PYC files.
In python, I could not find any module for code signing.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Well a solution would be to freeze your Python code and then you will be able to sign the resulting exe.

For some info on how to freeze your Python you can start by taking a look at [this](https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/freezing/).